# Can i insert data into database using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I Am Trying insert data in database using Post method to send Ajax ..what shroud I do?

```
$.post("action_insert .php", { id: id, data: data},
```

Comment: Not enough information provided in the question. What's in `action_insert.php`? What's going wrong? Do you have any errors? Is data JSON? Is the above as far as you've gotten? It's expected that you show
what effort you have put in to [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [solving](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your problem.

Comment: We can't help with your question when incomplete. Take a look at [w3schools jQuery Ajax Post tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp).

Comment: i am getting this error jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Your line of code is missing a closing brace (`)`), there is no callback parameter and there is a space in the filename?
Your code should probably look more: `$.post("action_insert.php", { id: id, data: data}, function result(){ alert('AJAX done'); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Post API. In API Level, you need to connect to DB, validate the data model in the body and do DB insert. Finally, acknowledge the API with a response.

From frontend, you need to request via AJAX.

This basic question and you can search online to get more details.